# WooCommerce change price to specific attribute taxonomy in variation

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product-variations

**Hello everyone,**

i need to make a function, that will increase price of a product based on value from attribute that user select. For example (not real product) - We have a product with T-shirt. Customer can choose from two attributes - **Color** and **Size**. Let say, that it look something like this:

1. Color: `Red / Blue / Green / Yellow / Black`
2. Size: `Small / Large`

So when customer pick his choice, the price will look like this:

---

**Any Color + Small** = 10$;
**Any Color + Large** = 20$;

---

Now i need to make a list with '**Premium**' colors. Let's assume it's *yellow* and i want that to increase the price by 20%. So now it should look like this:

---

**Any Color (without yellow) + Small** = 10$;
**Yellow + Small** = 12$;
**Any Color (without yellow) + Large** = 20$;
**Yellow + Large** = 24$;

---

I can't make it from default product variations in Woo, because of a large amount of them.

So i make a textarea with ACF, where i can put simplified name of attribute taxonomy.
I wrote a function, that check available variations for product and get ID's

Here's my code

```
function increase_price() {
    
  global $product;
  $regularPrice = $product->get_price();
  if($product->get_type() === 'variable') {
     $variations = $product->get_children();
     foreach($variations as $variation) {

         $vproduct = wc_get_product($variation);
         $premiumList = get_field( "color_list", 3096 ); // From ACF - field with 'premium colors'
         $premiumSep = explode(",", $premiumList);          
                
                
          $vNames = $vproduct->attributes{"pa_color"};
          if (in_array($vNames, $premiumSep)){

             $markupPrice = $vproduct->get_price();
             $selfVarID = $vproduct->get_id();
             $VarPrice = $markupPrice * 1.2;
             $VarPrice = ceil($VarPrice);
            
                    
            // update_post_meta( $selfVarID, '_regular_price', $VarPrice );
            // update_post_meta( $selfVarID, '_price', $VarPrice ); 
            // ^ it change the price in backend

                    
            } else {

            }   
      }
  }
        
}
```

So it works with '**update_post_meta**' but if someone change the price via Backend (Product Edit), it won't increase the price. My question is, how i can change the price *permanently* only for taxonomies on list?

**Thanks and have a great day :)**

Answer (score 0):

If someone saves the product in wp-admin, you can trigger your function on `save_post_product` hook

For example, simplified version of your code

```
function increase_variation_prices_on_save($post_id) {
    $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
    if($product->get_type() === 'variable') {
        $variations = $product->get_children();
        foreach($variations as $variation_id) {
            $vproduct = wc_get_product($variation_id);
                $markupPrice = $vproduct->get_price();
                $VarPrice = $markupPrice * 1.2;
                $VarPrice = ceil($VarPrice);
                update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', $VarPrice );
                update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_price', $VarPrice );
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post_product', 'increase_variation_prices_on_save', 10, 1);
```

but, there is **one problem** , this will increase the price **every time** you save your parent product!
It happens because your base price is the variation price so every time you save, the last increased price becomes the new base price.

Instead, you should pull the base price, or markup price from the parent product, before the loop, like this.

```
function increase_variation_prices_on_save($post_id) {
    $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
    $markupPrice = $product->get_price();
    if($product->get_type() === 'variable') {
        $variations = $product->get_children();
        foreach($variations as $variation_id) {
            $vproduct = wc_get_product($variation_id);
                $VarPrice = $markupPrice * 1.2;
                $VarPrice = ceil($VarPrice);
                update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_regular_price', $VarPrice );
                update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_price', $VarPrice );
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post_product', 'increase_variation_prices_on_save', 10, 1);
```

But what is the price of the parent product if you can't configure it in wp-admin? It's the price you add when you create variations. WooCommerce will ask you to set a price for all variations that don't have price. It's then stored in `_price` metadata under the parent product id.

And finally, your function which I wasn't able to test, it would take me too much time to create a setup like yours but it should work.

```
function increase_price() {

    global $product;
    $basePrice = $product->get_price();
    if($product->get_type() === 'variable') {
        $variations = $product->get_children();
        foreach($variations as $variation) {

            $vproduct = wc_get_product($variation);
            $premiumList = get_field( "color_list", 3096 ); // From ACF - field with 'premium colors'
            $premiumSep = explode(",", $premiumList);


            $vNames = $vproduct->attributes["pa_color"];
            if (in_array($vNames, $premiumSep)){

                $selfVarID = $vproduct->get_id();
                $VarPrice = $basePrice * 1.2;
                $VarPrice = ceil($VarPrice);

                update_post_meta( $selfVarID, '_regular_price', $VarPrice );
                update_post_meta( $selfVarID, '_price', $VarPrice );


            } 
        }
    }
}
```

**Have a great day too :)**